# RSA SecurID Sofware Token application window not visible after screen configuration change

Tags: windows-10, rsa, token

I regularly use the [RSA SecurID Software Token Application](https://community.rsa.com/t5/securid-software-token-for/tkb-p/securid-software-token-microsoft-windows) on a Windows 10 laptop. Sometimes after my displays get refonfigured (because switching external displays), the application windows is not visible after starting the app. The app is still visible on the taskbar and in the Task Manager.

How do I get the window to show up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is a slightly modified variant of [PAULGIBSON's solution found at RSA Link Community](https://community.rsa.com/t5/securid-access-discussions/rsa-token-for-windows-10-not-appearing/td-p/454568).

Open regedit.exe and remove the following keys storing information about the application window position:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\RSA\Software Token\Desktop\LastXPosition
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\RSA\Software Token\Desktop\LastYPosition
```

Restart the application after removing the keys.

Comment: thanks a lot! the old method that once worked for me (changing X.Y to big/small number) was not helping this time, until I found this answer.

Comment: Have anyone figure out how to do this for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

To recover an off-screen window:

1. Focus the window (e.g. Alt+Tab to it).
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to open the window menu.
3. Choose "<kbd>M</kbd>ove" in the menu.
4. Press an arrow key (in any direction).
5. Move your mouse and the window will jump to the cursor.

Comment: This is a great workaround for users without administrator privileges, thanks!

Comment: You don't need administrator privileges to modify HKEY_CURRENT_USER... Though the advantage of this method is that it works with all apps. (And all Windows versions.)

Comment: Have anyone figure out how to do this for Mac OSX?

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to it being a new account, but stumbled across this whilst looking for something else and thought I'd add my solution which is similar to above and have it happen frequently when switching between docking station and laptop screen..

I have a shortcut on the desktop called fixRSAWindowPosition which calls a script with a similar name ie fixRSAWindowPosition.cmd

this contains:

```
@Echo Off
taskkill /im:securid.exe /f
Powershell "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\RSA\Software Token\Desktop' -Name 'LastXPosition' -Value 0; Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\RSA\Software Token\Desktop' -Name 'LastYPosition' -Value 0
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Software Token\securid.exe"
```

I can't remember why I didn't write it all in powershell at the time, but it works for me.